# Understanding functions a little better

Tags: r

I learn by example so because I haven't seen a example yet on how to solve this problem so I am asking.

This is in R.

So lets say I make a matrix below.

Now I would like to make a function/loop that will only add the numbers before a 0 in each column.

I have no idea how to loop the function through this to drop the column or values after the zero. If you could explain as well that would be appreciated.

In this case the output should be 14

```r
a <- c(5, 0, 4, 0)
b <- c(0, 4, 5, 3)
c <- c(0, 3, 0, 6)

matrix <- rbind(a, b, c)
```

Comment: Provide what you want the output to be too. Your description isn't entirely clear to me.

Comment: updated sorry bout that

Comment: @rawr he wants to get 5 + 5 + 4

Comment: so `sum(matrix[, matrix[1, ] != 0])`? what about values in columns that do not start with 0 but occur after 0, for example, `rbind(a, b, c, d = c(0, 0, 1, 0))`, is the answer 14 or 15?

Comment: Residential <-  function(x){
  sum(x[, x[1, ] != 0])
}

Comment: @rawr it is 14 the point is that any numbers above the 0 in the column should be counted but any number below a 0 in a column will not be counted so for example if I changed it a round a little `a<- c(5, 1, 4, 0) b <- (0, 0, 5, 3,), c <- c(0, 3, 0, 6)`. then the answer would be 15. So it should work no matter what matrix is inputted into it.

Comment: Here's a hint - for a vector `x`, `x[cumsum(x == 0) == 0]` is all the values before the first 0.

Comment: @GregorThomas So I was playing around with the 'cumsum' and reading when I change the second number it does some weird things. How is this running through the matrices or am I making this to complex?

Comment: That `cumsum` approach would work for a single vector - or in your case a single column. All it does is subset the numbers before the first 0. You probably want to modify it (because you want to add the result), and then you would want to use a `for` loop or the `apply` function to apply it to every column.

Comment: @gregorThomas Thank you for that. I tried doing a for loop and couldn't get the syntax right. I am getting further with apply but I have come up with `Residential <-  function(x){
 apply(x[(x == 0) == 0], FUN = cumsum)
}` I keep getting a error that x must have a positive length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll stop being coy and post an answer - using the sample data from your question, here's how I'd approach figuring out what to do:

```
## pick a column to experiment with
x = matrix[, 3]
x
# a b c 
# 4 5 0 

## verify we can get all the entries before the first 0 
x[cumsum(x == 0) == 0]
# a b 
# 4 5 

## add them - this is good, we want to do this to every column
sum(x[cumsum(x == 0) == 0])
[1] 9

## do this to every column
## it works on the 0-first columns too! We don't need to go
## back and fix anything.
apply(matrix, 2, function(x) sum(x[cumsum(x == 0) == 0]))
# [1] 5 0 9 0

## and then we want to add up the results from each column
sum(apply(matrix, 2, function(x) sum(x[cumsum(x == 0) == 0])))
# [1] 14

## turn it into a function
residential = function(matrix) {
  sum(apply(matrix, 2, function(x) sum(x[cumsum(x == 0) == 0])))
}

## test it out
residential(matrix)
# [1] 14
```

Comment: I wouldn't say coy. It was nice to have someone to talk it out with. Even though this might be simple for yourself for me in coding terms I am still a babe in the woods. So I apricate it I will study this code to see if I can do it using a for loop as well.